# I want to access controls of derive class from base class on onLoad() override in c# (Master page derive from one masterClass)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I defined multiple master and has some common functionality on Form_Load event. Now I declare a customMasterPage class derived from System.Web.UI.MasterPage and put all common functionality into this. But I want to override onPage_Load() and want to print into controls of Dervived  class.

Suppose I have one customMaster Class

```
class customMasterClass:System:web.UI.MasterPage
{
    override onLoad()
     {
        base(e)

        //I want to use following child class controls(lblName) here to print
        // lblName.text=""
     }
}

class child1:customMaster
{
     //Controls are..
     //Label:id=lblName;

    Form_load()
    {
        lblName.text="test1 test1"; 
    }
}
class child2:customMaster
{
     //Controls are..
     //Label:id=lblName;

    Form_load()
    {
        lblName.text="test2 test2"; 
    }
}
```

How to do that. Please give me your advice

Thanks in Advance

Comment: In the `onPageLoad()` in the derived page classes, you may have to pass the fields you want to change up to the method in the base class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base classes don't know anything about the child classes. That being said, you can define the base class as having overridable methods that the derived class can use to set specific things, like:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public override OnLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        SetLabels();        //This will call the appropriate child class method
    }

    public virtual void SetLabels()
    {

    }
}

public class ChildClass1 : BaseClass
{
    public override void SetLabels()
    {
        //Set the label here
    }
}

public class ChildClass2 : BaseClass
{
    public override void SetLabels()
    {
        //Set the label here
    }
}
```